# SFMC Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud

How we can get the short code or long code in mobile connect in salesforce marketing cloud ?

please help me to find out that issue because i am not able to find it how we can get the short code or long code.

Answer (score 1):

You must reach out to your Account Executive at Salesforce to initiate the provisioning process

Comment: Hi Lukas
Thanks for helping me please can you give me steps or explain more so it is easy for me to find out solution for that.